# How to read multiple .xls files in r?

Tags: r, lapply, readxl

I have 18 files(.xls) in list and I want to read them in one go

Here is my codes below:

`filenames=list.files("C:/Users/ozgur.alptekin/Downloads/elif")`

`df.list=lapply(filenames, function(x) read_excel(file = x,sheetIndex = 1,as.data.frame = TRUE,header = TRUE))`

it did not work

Could you please tell me what I have done wrong and how I should do it?

Comment: how did it not work? was there an error?

Comment: @Adam Spannbauer  The error says:`Error in read_excel(file = x, sheetIndex = 1, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (file = x, sheetIndex = 1, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = TRUE)`

Comment: see `?read_excel` the arguments you're using are not the documented arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply try a loop?

```
filenames=list.files("C:/Users/ozgur.alptekin/Downloads/elif")

for (i in 1:length(filenames) {
assign(paste0("file_", i), 
read_excel(file = filenames[i],sheetIndex = 1, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = TRUE), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

reply if it works.

Comment: You're missing a closed parentheses on line 2.   I use sheet=2, range="A8:R45" and drop the sheetIndex and as.data.frame arguments because they are not specified in the read_excel usage notes.  However, I still get an error:  "unexpected `{` in "for (i in 1:length(files.list)..."  Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same code with some changes.
Under read_excel:

1. Use sheet instead of sheetindex
2. remove "file=" and just mention x
3. Don't think as.data.frame works in read_excel

Then,

```
filenames=list.files("C:/Users/ozgur.alptekin/Downloads/elif")    
df.list=lapply(filenames, function(x) read_excel(x,sheet = 1,header = TRUE))
```

**Then to convert it into a data.frame format, use the below**

**Appending of all the different data into one master data**

```
master_file = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,df.list))
```